# Problem with the solution of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

My try:

[image]

$\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Start by noticing that $P$ doesn't appear in the end result.  So,  we must eliminate it , instead of $Q$. Multiply by $y_2$  to the first and $y_1$ to the second and subtract to get 
$$y_2 \frac{dy_1}{dx}  - y_1 \frac{dy_2}{dx}  = Q(y_2-y_1) $$
Then substitute $y_2 = y_1*z$ and integrate it to get the answer.  Remember P and Q are functions of $x$. Your attempt shows that you forgot it while solving (integration part).

Comment if you any more help.